How do I satisfy this dependency osgi bundle?
I'm trying to build an eclipse plugin but it fails because it requires org.junit osgi bundle.
How can I provide this bundle to the build ?
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: org.scala-ide.p2-update-site.feature.feature.group 4.7.1.qualifier
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: org.scala-refactoring.library 0.14.0.2_12-201709132327-af879be requires 'osgi.bundle; org.junit 4.11.0' but it could not be found
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: org.scala-ide.p2-update-site.feature.feature.group 4.7.1.qualifier depends on: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.scala-refactoring.library 0.0.0
[ERROR]
[ERROR] See https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Dependency_Resolution_Troubleshooting for help.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for org.scala-ide.p2-toolchain 4.7.1-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] org.scala-ide.p2-toolchain ......................... SUCCESS [  0.104 s]
[INFO] org.scala-ide.zinc ................................. SUCCESS [  0.003 s]
[INFO] org.scala-ide.zinc.feature ......................... SUCCESS [  3.539 s]
[INFO] org.scala-ide.zinc.source.feature .................. SUCCESS [  1.528 s]
[INFO] org.scala-ide.zinc.update-site ..................... SUCCESS [  0.827 s]
[INFO] org.scala-ide.scala212.build ....................... SUCCESS [  0.003 s]
[INFO] org.scala-ide.scala212.feature ..................... SUCCESS [  0.521 s]
[INFO] org.scala-ide.scala212.source.feature .............. SUCCESS [  0.123 s]
[INFO] org.scala-ide.scala212.update-site ................. SUCCESS [  0.207 s]
[INFO] org.scala-ide.p2-update-site ....................... SUCCESS [  0.003 s]
[INFO] org.scala-ide.p2-update-site.feature ............... FAILURE [  0.247 s]
[INFO] org.scala-ide.p2-update-site.update-site ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  13.893 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-04-13T22:19:56+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

I tried adding junit in the dependency section :
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>

After that I had a new warning :
[WARNING] Maven Artifact junit:junit:4.11 is not a bundle and was automatically wrapped with bundle-symbolic name org.scala-ide.junit.junit, ignoring such artifacts can be enabled with <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies> in target platform configuration.
[INFO] The artifact can be referenced in feature files with the following data: <plugin id="org.scala-ide.junit.junit" version="4.11" download-size="0" install-size="0" unpack="false"/>

I followed the hint given in the message and added this line to the feature.xml :
    <plugin id="org.scala-ide.junit.junit" version="4.11" download-size="0" install-size="0" unpack="false"/>

below the 2 other plugin entries:
   <plugin
         id="org.scala-refactoring.library"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="scalariform"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

The pom is :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.scala-ide</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.scala-ide.p2-toolchain</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../org.scala-ide.p2-toolchain/pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>org.scala-ide.p2-update-site</artifactId>
  <description>The local p2 repo for scala-refactoring</description>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>4.7.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-refactoring</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.scala-refactoring.library_2.12.2</artifactId>
      <version>${scala-refactoring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scalariform</groupId>
      <artifactId>scalariform_${scala.minor.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${scalariform.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>scala-ide.refactoring.repo</id>
      <name>Scala IDE refactoring repository</name>
      <url>${repo.scala-refactoring}</url>
      <snapshots>
        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <modules>
    <module>org.scala-ide.p2-update-site.feature</module>
    <module>org.scala-ide.p2-update-site.update-site</module>
  </modules>

</project>

I don't have a target platform artifact where I would do something like:
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
  <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2024-03/"/>
  <unit id="org.junit" version="0.0.0"/>
</location>

Can I still add org.junit to the target platform in my maven pom.xml ?

The proper org.junit plug-in is in any of the main Eclipse repositories, so add one of those to your target platform. The current version is 4.13, if you need the exact 4.11 it was in Eclipse 4.3 - 4.4. The message from Tycho is just a warning, did it not build after that?

I've mistaken the "requires osgi bundle" for a "requires java package". The warning was related to the addition of the junit pom dependency. But I still have the error  "requires osgi bundle" anyway. Please see my last edit regarding targeted platform.

The log looks likes a Maven/Tycho build (... requires 'osgi.bundle; org.junit 4.11.0' ...), but the shown POM is not Tycho (<packaging>pom</packaging>). The missing requirement is missing in the target platform. In a Maven/Tycho the dependencies section is ignored. Please show the parent POM you run and from which the log you showed is.

I added this to the pom and that solved at least the part of the build requiring osgi bundle junit :
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <dependency-resolution>
            <extraRequirements>
              <requirement>
                <type>eclipse-plugin</type>
                <id>org.junit</id>
                <versionRange>4.11.0</versionRange>
              </requirement>
            </extraRequirements>
          </dependency-resolution>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

